# Firefox not setting the right content-type for multipart request

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Given the following javascript code (a simple upload script):

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file", document.getElementById('file').files[0]);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
xhr.open("POST", 'http://localhost:22977/home/upload');

xhr.send(fd);
```

`IE 10` and `Chrome 28.x.x.x` will send the post request with the `Content-Type` set as `multipart/form-data`. However `Firefox 21` will set it as `application/json`.

Setting the `Content-Type` by:

`xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");`

Still doesn't affect the `Content-Type` when `Firefox` is making the request.

How can I make `Firefox` use the *right* `Content-Type`?

**EDIT**

`IE 10` and `Chrome 28.x.x.x` request headers:

[image]

`Firefox 21` request headers:

[image]

Comment: setRequestHeader must be set after .open() did you do that?

Comment: well, I can't reproduce the problem here

Comment: This seems unlikely to be a bug in Firefox.  How are you verifying the Content-Type header?  Please post a screenshot or paste from firebug showing the request headers.

Comment: Also, you definitely should not set the Content-Type header for multipart requests manually.  The browser adds the multipart boundary as a parameter to this header value, which is critical.

Comment: @RayNicholus, Touché. - Updated the post with screenshots of request headers. - I'm using fiddler, and I've checked firebug - gives the same headers.

Comment: Hmm, I use Firefox to send MPE requests via FormData regularly, and was doing so without issue in 21 for some time.  It has to be some plugin you have installed, I would think.  Disable all Firefox extensions and try again.

Comment: @RayNicholus, That was it! - The extension `Modify Headers` somehow modified the `Content-Type` although no `Actions/Rules` were added to it. - Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I've created an answer based on my comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Firefox to send MPE requests via FormData regularly, and was doing so without issue in 21 for some time. It has to be some plugin you have installed, I would think. Disable all Firefox extensions and try again.